# Which statistical method to use for feature selection between numerical inputs and categorical input?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, pipelines

I have a classification problem where my inputs are all numerical and continuous, my outputs are categorical labels `[1,0,-1]`. My own domain knowledge and understanding of ML workflow tells me some features are redundant and don't provide much predictive insight to my model.

I am using Sklearns `SelectKBest()` package. However there are numerous statistical tests to conduct such methods. So my question is, given my inputs and outputs, which statistical method is best for my situation?

Furthermore, I wish to implement this step in Sklearns `pipeline()` package with GridSearch. My pipeline is quite rudimentary at this point but I still don't know which step this should be conducted. Would appreciate your answer guys.

My pipeline code is as follows:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('sc', preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()), 
                 ('SVM', svm.SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovr', kernel = 'poly'))])

    candidate_parameters = [{'SVM__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10], 'SVM__gamma': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]}]

    print('Fitting model...')
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = candidate_parameters, cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train )
```